# VM Player Ubuntu upgrade from 12.04 to 16.04 failed - entering into emergency mode

Tags: 12.04, 16.04, gparted, vmware

I'm upgrading Ubuntu from **12.04** to **16.04** in VM Ware Player version 5.0.4.

When using Ubuntu 12.04, i increased Hard disk size from 150GB to 300GB manually in VM player by mistake.(VM ware located in D:/ drive, which is 232GB in size).

However, I couldn't see 300GB replicated in Ubuntu(was not knowing that i should use Gparted to increase partition from 150GB to 300GB).

After installation Ubuntu is entering into **Emergency mode** as shown:
[Emergency mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWeyf.png)

Someone, please point out where am i going wrong?

1). I cannot install successfully because hard disk wrong increment to 300GB out of 232GB?

2). If I remove old 12.04 files and install 16.04, is it still possible to access data from 12.04's **DSU.vmdk** file?

3). Is it possible to reduce 300GB to 150GB using Gparted in VMWare player?
(150GB is still unallocated)

Comment: Let me get you, you are trying to upgrade Ubuntu in a VM?

Comment: Yes, I give path to Ubuntu 16.04 iso image in Vm Ware, installation possible(everything will be erased except home directory).

Comment: Please see my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you correctly your trying to upgrade Ubuntu from `12.04` to `16.04` in a virtual machine. I don't think that's possible in a Virtual device, only real installs can get upgraded. You have to store those files using a folder in you `host` system, then install the new version using a newly downloaded Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: After installing newly downloaded Ubuntu 16.04, is it still possible to access data from 12.04's DSU.vmdk file?

Comment: Please put that data in a file in the host system and after installing the new OS add that folder to it.